# can I attach an anchor tag on a span text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I open up a link when I click on the span items. This is what I have done

https://codepen.io/errors101/pen/LYNezVv?editors=1100

I don't want to put anchor tag inside every span element instead I want to use onClick to edit the html to insert a link only when someone clicks on it.
How can I do this ?

```css
nav {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.link:after {
  content: "";
  /*     display:block; */
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #2987FF;
  transition: width .18s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95)
}

.link:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes colours1 {
  0% {
    color: #00f;
  }
  50% {
    color: #0f0;
  }
  75% {
    color: #000;
  }
  100% {
    color: #f00;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes colours2 {
  0% {
    color: red;
  }
  50% {
    color: green;
  }
  75% {
    color: black;
  }
  100% {
    color: blue;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes colours3 {
  0% {
    color: purple;
  }
  50% {
    color: yellow;
  }
  75% {
    color: violet;
  }
  100% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes colours4 {
  0% {
    color: orange;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
  75% {
    color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    color: purple;
  }
}

#a {
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: colours1;
  /* -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease; */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(3, end);
}

#b {
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: colours2;
  /* -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease; */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(2, end);
}

#c {
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: colours3;
  /* -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease; */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(2, end);
}

#d {
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: colours4;
  /* -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease; */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(2, end);
}

em {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-style: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!--   <nav>
     <a class="link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
  </nav> -->

<em>
    <spam id= "a">P</spam>
    <spam id= "b">o</spam>
    <spam id= "c">r</spam>
    <spam id= "d">t</spam>
    <spam id= "b">f</spam>
    <spam id= "c">o</spam>
    <spam id= "d">l</spam>
    <spam id= "c">i</spam>
    <spam id= "a">o</spam>
  </em>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. PLEASE do not try to bypass Stackoverflow when they ask you to post code

Comment: I did know this but i have seen people to post the liks of jsfiddle that's why i directly posted the codepen link of mine. I'll keep that in mind from next time, thanks.

Comment: suppose someone is clicking on a button which has an anchor tag inside it, here "open up a link" means if a user click on the span word or the letter it should open a link attatch to it just like an anchor tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

Note I had to change your ID to CLASS since you cannot reuse an ID

```js
const linksObj = {
  a: "https://google.com",
  b: "https://msdn.com",
  c: "",
  d: "",
  e: "",
  f: "",
  g: "",
  h: "",
  i: ""
}
document.querySelector("#links").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName === "SPAN") {
    location = linksObj[tgt.id]
  }
})
```

```css
nav {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.link:after {
  content: "";
  /*     display:block; */
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #2987FF;
  transition: width .18s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95)
}

.link:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes colours1 {
  0% {
    color: #00f;
  }
  50% {
    color: #0f0;
  }
  75% {
    color: #000;
  }
  100% {
    color: #f00;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes colours2 {
  0% {
    color: red;
  }
  50% {
    color: green;
  }
  75% {
    color: black;
  }
  100% {
    color: blue;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes colours3 {
  0% {
    color: purple;
  }
  50% {
    color: yellow;
  }
  75% {
    color: violet;
  }
  100% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes colours4 {
  0% {
    color: orange;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
  75% {
    color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    color: purple;
  }
}

.a {
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: colours1;
  /* -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease; */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(3, end);
}

.b {
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: colours2;
  /* -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease; */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(2, end);
}

.c {
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: colours3;
  /* -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease; */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(2, end);
}

.d {
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: colours4;
  /* -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease; */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(2, end);
}

em {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-style: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<em id="links">
    <span id="a" class="a">P</span>
    <span id="b" class="b">o</span>
    <span id="c" class="c">r</span>
    <span id="d" class="d">t</span>
    <span id="e" class="e">f</span>
    <span id="f" class="f">o</span>
    <span id="g" class="d">l</span>
    <span id="h" class="c">i</span>
    <span id="i" class="a">o</span>
  </em>
```

Clicking on portfolio to go to ONE link

```js
const linksObj = {
  portfolio: "https://google.com/search?q=portfolio",
  about: "https://google.com/search?q=about",
  contact: "https://google.com/search?q=about"
}
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.parentNode.classList.contains("link")) tgt = tgt.parentNode; // allow one level up
  if (tgt.classList.contains("link")) location = linksObj[tgt.id];
})
```

```css
nav {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.link:after {
  content: "";
  /*     display:block; */
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #2987FF;
  transition: width .18s cubic-bezier(0.45, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95)
}

.link:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes colours1 {
  0% {
    color: #00f;
  }
  50% {
    color: #0f0;
  }
  75% {
    color: #000;
  }
  100% {
    color: #f00;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes colours2 {
  0% {
    color: red;
  }
  50% {
    color: green;
  }
  75% {
    color: black;
  }
  100% {
    color: blue;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes colours3 {
  0% {
    color: purple;
  }
  50% {
    color: yellow;
  }
  75% {
    color: violet;
  }
  100% {
    color: black;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes colours4 {
  0% {
    color: orange;
  }
  50% {
    color: black;
  }
  75% {
    color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    color: purple;
  }
}

.a {
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: colours1;
  /* -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease; */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(3, end);
}

.b {
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: colours2;
  /* -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease; */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(2, end);
}

.c {
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: colours3;
  /* -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease; */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(2, end);
}

.d {
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-name: colours4;
  /* -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease; */
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: steps(2, end);
}

em {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-style: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <em class="link" id="portfolio">
    <span class="a">P</span>
    <span class="b">o</span>
    <span class="c">r</span>
    <span class="d">t</span>
    <span class="e">f</span>
    <span class="f">o</span>
    <span class="d">l</span>
    <span class="c">i</span>
    <span class="a">o</span>
  </em>

  <span id="about" class="link">About</span>

  <p id="contact" class="link">contact</p>
</div>
```

Comment: exactly this way but then I have to assign same links for every tag right ? Because a user can click on any portion of the whole word

Comment: Of course not. If you want to link to portfolio.html on click on any letter, you just assign the handler to the container and test what is clicked- see update

Comment: can you tell me what this line is doing
`if (tgt.classList.contains("link")) location = linksObj[tgt.id];`

Comment: if the clicked target (or in my script its parentNode) has a class="link"

Comment: I do understand that you are checking for the class named "link" but how is this referencing to the links in your linksObj object

Comment: IF the element has class=link THEN use the ID of the element to address the object called linksObj